cannot find the redis statefulset pvc define in kubernetes redis statefulset yaml
I tried to rename the statefulset pvc in kubernetes. But I could not find where the pvc is defined. This is the kubernetes yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: reddwarf-redis-master
  namespace: reddwarf-cache
status:
  observedGeneration: 2
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  currentRevision: reddwarf-redis-master-686f568db9
  updateRevision: reddwarf-redis-master-6bc6b78474
  collisionCount: 0
  availableReplicas: 0
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-redis
      app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: master
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-redis
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
        helm.sh/chart: redis-17.8.0
      annotations:
        checksum/configmap: 58007696c1a7ce9392e17b3fbc0176ecb231bd1e89e424833ae87abe6180ba70
        checksum/health: 617c81318616bf8cc32a4e21b4435b4c46859317d4453830d73eb1039493b9ac
        checksum/scripts: 92ddb483b2fac55ea06a3c2c48cf2d866e10764d4b75ac10fbf25f346ed20c9b
        checksum/secret: 35b6246ede69a46a5b9831e24c6072747d26e626c21eb90a24df49de3531e70c
        kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: '2024-07-04T14:47:55Z'
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: start-scripts
          configMap:
            name: reddwarf-redis-scripts
            defaultMode: 493
        - name: health
          configMap:
            name: reddwarf-redis-health
            defaultMode: 493
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: reddwarf-redis-configuration
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: redis-tmp-conf
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: tmp
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: >-
            registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-public/redis:7.0.8-debian-11-r13
          command:
            - /bin/bash
          args:
            - '-c'
            - /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts/start-master.sh
          ports:
            - name: redis
              containerPort: 6379
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
              value: 'false'
            - name: REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE
              value: master
            - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
              value: 'no'
            - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: reddwarf-redis
                  key: redis-password
            - name: REDIS_TLS_ENABLED
              value: 'no'
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: '6379'
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: start-scripts
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/scripts/start-scripts
            - name: health
              mountPath: /health
            - name: redis-data
              mountPath: /data
            - name: config
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/redis/mounted-etc
            - name: redis-tmp-conf
              mountPath: /opt/bitnami/redis/etc/
            - name: tmp
              mountPath: /tmp
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - sh
                - '-c'
                - /health/ping_liveness_local.sh 5
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 6
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - sh
                - '-c'
                - /health/ping_readiness_local.sh 1
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 5
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1001
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: reddwarf-redis
      serviceAccount: reddwarf-redis
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 1
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app.kubernetes.io/component: master
                    app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-redis
                    app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: redis-data
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          app.kubernetes.io/component: master
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: reddwarf-redis
          app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 8Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
      status:
        phase: Pending
  serviceName: reddwarf-redis-headless
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
    whenDeleted: Retain
    whenScaled: Retain

I can find the pvc in lens like this:

but there is no help in yaml on where I could find the PVC redis-data-reddwarf-redis-master-0. Is it possible to rename the redis-data-reddwarf-redis-master-0 to redis-data-reddwarf-redis-master-0-qingdao?
